# Spotify - get playlist track names

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

On `search endpoint`, one can retrieve `playlist` data, for instance:

```
def search_playlist():

    results = sp.search(q='doom metal', type='playlist')
```

If I add this to the code:

```
    items = results['playlists']['items'][0]['tracks']
    print (items)
```

I get:

`{u'total': 349, u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/handiofiblood/playlists/71CdtOFANPpdboCh6e8lHr/tracks'}`

But how do I access **track names**, given the fact that the `id` at this `endpoint` stands for the `playlist` and not the `tracks` themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/user_playlists_contents.py

```
def show_tracks(results):
for i, item in enumerate(tracks['items']):
    track = item['track']
    print("   %d %32.32s %s" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
```

and

```
    playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)
    for playlist in playlists['items']:
        if playlist['owner']['id'] == username:
            print()
            print(playlist['name'])
            print('  total tracks', playlist['tracks']['total'])
            results = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist['id'], fields="tracks,next")
            tracks = results['tracks']
            show_tracks(tracks)
            while tracks['next']:
                tracks = sp.next(tracks)
                show_tracks(tracks)
```